# cube.js: send raw sql query to cube server

Tags: cube.js

Is it possible to send a raw sql request to a cubejs server? The cubejs server would send it as is to the db it is connected to? I have some edge cases where I would like to let the client send raw sql requests instead of using the cube query format.

Answer (score 1):

The Cube.js way to working with a database would be to create a [data schema](https://cube.dev/docs/schema/getting-started) and write queries in Cube.js format. Then, Cube.js will take care of SQL generation and execution. While, technically, you can have quite complex statements in your cubes’ SQL [definitions](https://cube.dev/docs/cube#parameters-sql), you will have to use Cube.js query format, anyway.